# Удаление связанных данных Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть связанные классы:

```
public class Theme: Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Path Parent { get; set; } // сейчас не имеет значения
}
public class Material:Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Theme Parent { get; set; } 
}
```

Как удалить только объект класса Theme? Чтобы объекты Material остались в таблице, но Parent и ParentId обнулились.
Пробовал так:

```
Theme currenttheme = db.DbThemes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == theme.Id);
//currenttheme.Materials.Clear();
db.DbThemes.Remove(currenttheme);
db.SaveChanges();
```

И так:

```
Theme currenttheme = db.DbThemes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == theme.Id);
currenttheme.Materials.Clear();
db.DbThemes.Remove(currenttheme);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Все равно выдает ошибки.В двух случаях:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
>   constraint "FK_dbo.Themes_dbo.Paths_ParentId". The conflict occurred
>   in database "userstore", table "dbo.Themes", column 'ParentId'.

Comment: "Все равно выдает ошибки" - какие?

Comment: @AK я так понял это связано с тем, что Theme тоже есть коллекцией другого класса (Path) ?

Comment: А как связаны таблицы Themes и Paths? Почему Paths "держит" Themes.ParentId?

Comment: Мммм... я знаю, какую [тему](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete) гуглить для ef core: Cascade  /   ClientSetNull - но уже подзабыл, как это в ef 6 делалось.

Comment: @Vlad Themes так же вложена в Path, как и Material в Theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решилось простой жадной загрузкой вложенностей

```
Theme currenttheme = db.DbThemes.Include(c =>c.Materials).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == theme.Id);
currenttheme.Materials.Clear();
db.DbThemes.Remove(currenttheme);
db.SaveChanges();
```